# Excel VBA - WorkbookBeforeSave Event Does

Tags: vba, excel

I have an add-in with an application object. The object is declared WithEvents. This enables me to flush some data points to a central database every time the user saves the file. This works most of the time. However, there is one user who quits the Excel application, which calls up the Save dialog box. It appears that quitting Excel with an unsaved file means that the WorkbookBeforeSave event does not fire.

Just to emphasize, I have confirmed that the event does fire when the user hits CTRL-S, or presses the save button. I have also confirmed that the event does NOT fire if I quit the application.

I can think of a few workarounds (automatically save every 10 seconds, for example), but I'm not crazy about that. Can anyone confirm this behavior and/or does anyone have a remedy?

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mapp As Excel.Application

Private Sub mapp_WorkbookBeforeSave(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    ' Sanity preservation device
    Msgbox "WorkbookBeforeSave event fired."
    SaveSomeData Wb

End Sub
```

Comment: so does the event fires at all? Maybe you want to make sure `Application.enableEvents = True`

Comment: Yes, the event does fire if I save the workbook using CTRL-S or pushing the save button in the ribbon. However, if I quit Excel (ALT-F4), then I will be prompted to save the file, but the WorkbookBeforeSave event won't be fired. If there were such a thing as OnQuit or something for the Application object, I'd use that. However, I don't see anything like that.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `Workbook_BeforeClose` routine and the Workbook Object's `Saved` property.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    If ThisWorkbook.Saved = False Then
        'Call save function
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use the BeforeClose event. Here's a bit more background: when I arrived here, there were hundreds of Excel files which had more or less the same coding, but there was a separate file for each customer. In trying to mine those files for information, I created an add-in which would write data to an Access db. To use BeforeClose, I'd have to add that event to hundreds of workbooks. Ugh. An additional problem is that the workbooks are all fairly big, around 15MB each. If I open ten of them, I run out of memory. We'll do this differently going forward, cleaning up legacy now.

Comment: Sounds like a rather sticky situation you've got going on there! Make sure you add all that to the question, I personally can't think of a neat solution but others may be able to. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using before BeforeClose? This might be a better alternative.